# Visual Studio 2019, problem with properties view

Tags: c#, view, properties

I need help with Visual Studio 2019. I have a problem with properties. On a first picture it's my Visual studio properties, as you can see left side of properties is fine but right side is hidden half way and I can't see whole words.

On a second picture, everything is good and you can see everything, how do I fix this problem so I can see everything like on a second picture?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: I think you have added the same picture twice as they look identical

Answer (score 2):

You could resize the size of this column by moving line between columns. To have more space you should resize full properties panel

Answer (score 1):

Move the line that separates the 2 columns